# Вывод большого количества данных

Tags: c#, вывод

Есть обычный Windows Form's и огромные объемы данных,которые надо на него вывести,желательно с выделением некоторых слов другим текстом + функция автоскролла.

Вопрос в том,как лучше и выгоднее это сделать.Пробовал через RichTextBox,чуть не заснул, пока он это делал.

Может кто сталкивался? Писать класс что-то не хочется...

```
{
    double[] a = new double[4000];
    for (int i = 0; i < 4000; i++)
    {
        a[i] = 2.66;
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < 3990; i++)
    {
        if ((a[i]>2.11) && (a[i]<4.11))
        {
            richTextBox1.Text += a[i]+" ";
            richTextBox1.Text += a[i+1] + " ";
            richTextBox1.Text += a[i+2] + " ";
            richTextBox1.Text += a[i+3] + " ";
            richTextBox1.Text += a[i+4] + Environment.NewLine;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: К примеру есть 10000+ чисел вида х.хх необходимо находить среди них комбинации ,к примеру первое число должно быть больше 1 и меньше 3,второе ..... и т.д. и выводить подходящие на экран.Просто их иногда бывает штук 300-300 и RichTextBox перестает справляться.А в c# я не особо опытный,так что хочу узнать Ваше мнение

Comment: В коде просто if a[i]>2 && a[i]<4

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Подправил.К примеру вот так.Тут будет 3995 строк

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Просто в том же Python или консоли C# такой проблемы никогда не было.А с Windows Forms всего неделю,поэтому жуткие затупы

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov Если ты самоучка,но хочется развиваться,то что поделать...Лучше выглядеть глупым и слушать более опытных,чем страдать)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Для объединения большого количества строк следует использовать класс [StringBuilder](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.stringbuilder?view=netcore-3.1). О нём обязательно рассказывают в каждом учебнике или курсе по C#.

Но конкатенация строк - это мелочь в вашем коде по сравнению с тем, что много тысяч раз обновляется свойство GUI-контрола - именно это тормозит: `richTextBox1.Text = ...` При каждом обновлении свойства графический контрол должен перерисоваться, проскроллиться и т. п. Поэтому следует сделать это один раз, присвоив ему сразу всё.

```
const int count = 4000;
double[] a = new double[count];

for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
{
    a[i] = 2.66;
}

var builder = new StringBuilder();

for (int i = 0; i < count - 5; i += 5)
{
    if ((a[i] > 2.11) && (a[i] < 4.11))
    {
        builder
            .Append(a[i]).Append(' ')
            .Append(a[i + 1]).Append(' ')
            .Append(a[i + 2]).Append(' ')
            .Append(a[i + 3]).Append(' ')
            .Append(a[i + 4]).AppendLine();
    }
}

richTextBox1.Text = builder.ToString();
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо)

Answer (score 1):

Для такого кол-ва данных я бы использовал ListView с включённым виртуальным режимом. Особенно, если данные будут обновляться.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {    
        double[] a = new double[10000];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView1.RetrieveVirtualItem += (sender, item) =>
                item.Item = new ListViewItem(a[item.ItemIndex].ToString("F3"), 0);
        }

        async private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.For(0, a.Length, i =>
                {
                    a[i] = RandomGen.Next();
                });    
            });
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.VirtualListSize = a.Length;
        }
    }

    public static class RandomGen
    {
        private static Random global = new Random();
        [ThreadStatic]
        private static Random local;

        public static int Next()
        {
            Random instance = local;
            if (instance == null)
            {
                int seed;
                lock (global) seed = global.Next();
                local = instance = new Random(seed);
            }
            return instance.Next(1,4);
        }
    }
}
```

Класс RandomGen и обработчик события button2_Click приведены лишь для генерации самих данных. Жертвуем ресурсами ради скорости.

В button1_Click указываем, что listView1 необходимо обновить свою коллекцию элементов в размере a.Length, затем необходимо обработать событие RetrieveVirtualItem, и собственно всё. Моментально заполняем данными наш listView1. (Ну, у меня на ПК это происходит моментально)

Comment: Гмм... Если всю эту параллельщину выкинуть - будет работать быстрее.

Comment: Благодарю,попробую)

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, спасибо за замечание, но я же сказал, что эта "параллельщина" приведена для примера генерации данных, чтобы показать работоспособность основного кода, на работу listView1 она никак не влияет, плюс, вся эта "параллельщина" достаточно быстро работает, за исключением того, что эта "параллельщина" ест много ресурсов машины.

Comment: @XupypG, не за что.

Comment: Я позволил себе немного отредактировать ваш код: удалил неиспользуемые переменные и ненужный цикл. Если вы несогласны, можете откатить правку назад.

Comment: Кстати, с тем циклом ваш код никак не мог выполняться моментально. Просто вы этого не замечали, т. к. он выполнялся в другом потоке, GUI не замерзал, а ListView заполняется виртуально. Если поставить после `await Task.Run`, например, `this.Text = "done";`, то сразу станет заметна пауза. Без цикла становится нормально (но всё равно медленнее, чем заполнение массива простым циклом в один поток, как в коде автора).

Comment: Не хотите ли запостить свой код в виде отдельного вопроса с пометкой "инспекция кода"? У меня зудит разобрать его. А комментарии не предназначены для этого.

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, огромное спасибо за замечания, никогда не был против того, чтобы поучится чему-то. Насчёт цикла понял. Позволил себе старую версию кода погонять, изменяя кол-во элементов в массиве a, если взять начальную точку в 10000, генерация происходила в течении ~1с., но при 100000 элементов генерация доходила до ~20c., что очень заметно. Насчёт инспекции кода, что, всё так плохо?)

Comment: Не то чтобы плохо, просто в распараллеливании столько нюансов... Плюс мне хотелось бы ещё раз посоветовать одну хорошую книгу по теме (в ней как раз код многопоточного заполнения массива без false sharing).

Comment: @AlexanderPetrov, перенёс код в [вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119395/%d0%9d%d1%8e%d0%b0%d0%bd%d1%81%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d1%80%d0%b0%d1%81%d0%bf%d0%b0%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bb%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%bb%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b8-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b4%d0%b0%d1%87%d0%b8-%d0%bf%d0%be-%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%be%d0%bb%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8e-%d0%bc%d0%b0%d1%81%d1%81%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0-%d0%b4%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%bc%d0%b8)