# Нюансы в распараллеливании задачи по заполнению массива данными

Tags: c#, инспекция-кода, распараллеливание

В целях инспекции кода и познании большего в распараллеливании, перенёс ответ из [()](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/1119047/%D0%92%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4-%D0%B1%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D1%88%D0%BE%D0%B3%D0%BE-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%B8%D1%87%D0%B5%D1%81%D1%82%D0%B2%D0%B0-%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85/1119067#1119067) в этот вопрос.

Изначальный вопрос:
Есть обычный Windows Form's и огромные объемы данных,которые надо на него вывести,желательно с выделением некоторых слов другим текстом + функция автоскролла. Вопрос в том,как лучше и выгоднее это сделать.Пробовал через RichTextBox,чуть не заснул ,пока он это делал. Может кто сталкивался?Писать класс что-то не хочется...

Дальше приведён код моего ответа на данный вопрос.

```
using System;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using System.Windows.Forms;

namespace Test
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        double[] a = new double[10000];

        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();

            listView1.RetrieveVirtualItem += (sender, item) =>
                item.Item = new ListViewItem(a[item.ItemIndex].ToString("F3"), 0);
        }

        async private void button2_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            await Task.Run(() =>
            {
                Parallel.For(0, a.Length, i =>
                {
                    a[i] = RandomGen.Next();
                });
            });
        }

        private void button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            listView1.VirtualListSize = a.Length;
        }
    }

    public static class RandomGen
    {
        private static Random global = new Random();
            [ThreadStatic]
        private static Random local;

        public static int Next()
        {
            Random instance = local;
            if (instance == null)
            {
                int seed;
                lock (global) seed = global.Next();
                local = instance = new Random(seed);
            }
            return instance.Next(1,4);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Так а вопрос в чем?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev - это не вопрос, а инспекция кода. Что в нём хорошо, что в нём плохо.

Comment: Я бы начал с того, что для заполнения 10к элементов не надо никакой параллельности. Второе - если вам надо пачку чисел сгенерировать, у Random вроде есть для этого специальные методы, типа GetBytes (не помню точно). Третье - вам необязательно создавать Random для создания других Random, вы можете воспользоваться, например, чем то типа `new Random(Guid.NewGuid().GetHashCode())`, хотя есть сомнения в полезности всего класса `RandomGen`.

Comment: В метке сказано: *Обязательно опишите реализуемую функциональность и назначение кода. Используйте стандартный для языка стиль кодирования — имена функций и переменных, отступы, пробелы и прочее. Подробная инструкция есть в полном описании.* Приведите вопрос в соответствие, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Как положительный момент я хочу отметить понимание того факта, что класс `Random` не является потокобезопасным. И поэтому создаётся свой экземпляр дла каждого потока.

Также радует понимание работы атрибута `ThreadStatic`. Хотя я ни разу не встречал его в реальном коде.

---

Десять тысяч элементов - это совсем немного. И заполнение массива простым циклом:

```
var random = new Random();

for (int i = 0; i < a.Length; i++)
{
    a[i] = random.NextDouble();
}
```

будет быстрее без распараллеливания. Потому что запуск потоков, пусть даже взятых из пула, - тоже требует времени.

---

Что ещё плохо в этом коде:

```
Parallel.For(0, a.Length, i =>
{
    a[i] = RandomGen.Next();
});
```

Тут *каждая* ячейка массива заполняется в отдельном потоке. Гораздо лучше будет разбить массив на диапазоны и заполнять каждый диапазон полностью в одном потоке.

Для этого удобно использовать метод `Partitioner.Create`. Пример:

```
var partitioner = Partitioner.Create(0, a.Length);

Parallel.ForEach(partitioner, range =>
{
    for (int i = range.Item1; i < range.Item2; i++)
    {
        a[i] = random.NextDouble();
    }
});
```

Больше информации по ссылке: [How to: Speed Up Small Loop Bodies](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/parallel-programming/how-to-speed-up-small-loop-bodies)

---

При каких размерах массива следует переходить на параллельность?

Для начала качаем небольшую (сто страниц) книгу [Patterns of parallel programming](https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=19222) by Stephen Toub. Это официально бесплатно.

В ней в разделе False sharing (стр. 44) есть пример многопоточного заполнения массивов. Размер там двадцать миллионов элементов. Вот на таких величинах распараллеливание окупается.

И там объяснен ещё один момент, который может сильно ухудшить производительность: False sharing.

Собственно я и затеял этот ответ, чтобы ещё раз порекламировать эту книгу и посоветовать всем дотнетчикам с ней ознакомиться (моя настольная книга).

Конкретно в вашем примере кода каждый экземпляр `Random`, вероятно, будет попадать в отдельную линию кэша, потому что они создаются не одновременно. Поэтому проблема [False sharing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/False_sharing) не стоит. Но о ней следует знать.