# Заполнение большого массива C#

Tags: c#, многопоточность, heap

Приложение на С# заполняяет List размером 1000000+ рандомных чисел и выводится в BoxList, + предусмотрена сортировка после создания. Это занимает больше 3-х минут и нагружает процессор на 25%. Как можно ускорить этот процесс?

```
List<int> info = new List<int>(n);
for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
info.Add(rand.Next(-1000, 1000));
```

Comment: Ваш код у меня отрабатывает за долю секунды, давайте самодостаточный пример, который воспроизведет проблему (скорей всего вы делаете сортировку каким то хитрым способом?).

Comment: @EvgeniyZ Возможно еще дело в том что я вывожу это в  BoxList. Не подумал об этом. Само заполнение 3 минуты.

Comment: Вот, это уже меняет дело в корне. Например вот ваша [генерация](https://dotnetfiddle.net/TvJGEt), отработала за `00:00:00.0184988`, это ничтожное время. А вот если вы там пропишите вывод в консоль всех этих значений, то вкладка у вас скорей всего зависнет от такого кол-ва данных. Для таких целей придумали пагинацию (страницы) и виртуализацию (когда грузится только та часть данных, которая видна пользователю), вот вам в эту сторону и надо двигаться. Я не знаю где вы там пишете, но вот первый попавшийся пример для [WinForms](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1119067/220553).

Comment: Еще убедитесь, что вы сначала генерируете все свои значения, а потом их выводите. А не генегриуете и выводите на форму по одному.

Comment: @tym32167 Сразу все